# Where's the native executable in my application?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-executable

I've got an application project which includes a jni native code (example.c) with the following makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := example
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := example.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

So I'm building it like an executable and everything goes right.
Is the executable "packed" with the application?
If yes, how do I get its path or its location in memory, so I can run it from the java code?

PS: I'm not building the native code as a shared library because I want to run a main function as root with shell commands, like this:

```
chmod 777 /path/exe
/path/exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory: `/jni` and another directory `/libs`. Now put your `example.c` and your `Android.mk` inside the `/jni` directory. Now `cd` to the `/jni` directory and type the command `ndk-build`. If your makefile is correct and there are no errors in you source files the under the `/libs` directory another new directory called `/armeabi` would be created. Inside this directory, your executable would be present.

To execute this executable the android device must be rooted or you can use the android emulator provided with SDK.

Further you need to place this executable into `/data/local/` location of your android device (because even though your device is rooted, you will not have execute permissions from other locations.

you can do so using the below command:

```
adb push example /data/local/
```

Now enter the `adb shell` mode and cd to `/data/local/`.

Change your file permissions: `chmod example 777`

Now in this same location you can place your shell file. Also you can access your sdcard and other folders from this directory.

Hope this is helpful to you. If everything works, don't forget to accept the answer.